# Why was the A-D-E type minimal model distinguished?

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory

One was reading the paper where one encountered a word called "A Type minimal model", which seemed to indicate some historical identification. Latter one found it in the Wikipedia that in the "Classification" of the minimal model, there was A,D,E three different types of the minimal models.(I remembered to have encountered the similiar notion in [the root system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system), or more familiar to be known as the [ADE classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADE_classification) )

But the minimal model was "sufficiently" labeled by $(p,q)$, and in the Francesco's book there wasn't a heavy mention between the A,D,E, series.(Might because the $p$ value for D and E series were relatively high.)

Especially, how was the physics between the A-D-E minimal model differ? For example, the following examples were listed in the Francesco,

> A series: $(p,q)=(3,2)$ : trivial CFT
> A Series: $(p,q)=(4,3)$ : critical Ising model
> D series: $(p,q)=(6,5)$ : 3-state Potts model at criticality
> D Series: $(p,q)=(7,6)$ : tricritical 3-state Potts model

They were the well known physical models, but it's hard to see how the evolution from the A series to the D series differ.

Why was the A-D-E type minimal model distinguished?

(A joke that was totally unrelated, though it was considered unprofessional to quote the Wikipedia, should it be worthy to quote all it references?)

Comment: Minimal models are not labeled by $(p,q)$. Their *chiral algebra* is, but not the CFT itself. A CFT is a chiral algebra *plus* a choice of modular invariant. The latter requires ADE labels.

Comment: To follow up, there are also $(p, q) = (6, 5)$ and $(p, q) = (7, 6)$ minimal models in the A-series which means the primary operators transform in the same representations of $\mathfrak{Vir}$ and $\overline{\mathfrak{Vir}}$. They are sometimes called the tetra-critical and penta-critical Ising models. The name signifies the number of relevant operators which can be generated by repeated fusions of $\phi_{2,2} \bar{\phi}_{2,2}$ which is the Landau-Ginzburg order parameter.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform What was the minimal model being labeled by?(I didn't quite under stand by labeling by subsequent ADE lattice.) I thought both the chiral algebra and the central charge was restricted by $(p,q)$, sometimes a subset of the characters could be selected to form a theory.

Comment: @ConnorBehan I did recall the the concept in the modular invariance. So, for the block diagonal cases, the D series meant orbifolds? But that was distinguished at the level of the theory, i.e. for the selective subsequent holomorphic and antiholomorphic combinations, is it?

Answer (score 1):

The integers $(p,q)$ only classify the holomorphic or anti-holomorphic part of a CFT. However, to get a full CFT, one needs to combine the holomorphic part and anti-holomorphic part to get a modular invariant theory. Of course, the *diagonal* case $\sum_{i}\chi_i\bar{\chi}_i$ is a legal choice but it is not the only choice. There exist *nondiagonal* cases where a $\chi_i$ may pair with $\bar{\chi}_{j\ne i}$. They (both diagonal and nondiagonal cases) turn out to have a relation with ADE classification.

Francesco's CFT discussed this in section 10.7, especially in Tables 10.3 and 10.4. For the proof and Lie-algebra interpretations, check *The A-D-E classification of minimal and $A_1^1$ conformal invariant theories* by Zuber et al.

[image]
[image]